# Passing variables between files

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send information between 2 files.

first file :

```
function findDepartment(codePostal,commune,deptId)
    {
        if (codePostal.length==5)
        {
        var fichier1 = "inclusions/ajax-cp-departement.php";
           $.ajax({
            url: fichier1,
            data: {codePostal: codePostal, commune: commune},
            success: function(response) {
                $(deptId).val(response);

            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                alert('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status);
            }
        });
        }
    }
```

Second file : "inclusions/ajax-cp-departement.php"

```
$commune = $_REQUEST['commune'];
$commune = trim($commune);
$codePostal= $_REQUEST['codePostal'];
$codePostal= trim($codePostal);

if (strlen($commune)>0 && strlen($codePostal)>0)
{
    // Liste les communes du département demandé
    $query = "SELECT departement
    FROM commune_zone
    WHERE commune LIKE '$commune' 
    AND code_postal LIKE '$codePostal' 
    LIMIT 1";
}
```

this is how i call my function :

```
findDepartment(monCp,$("#ville_projet").val(), "#departement_projet");
```

the commune variable is not detected since it sends an empty result, when i remove commune it works, any ideas why do I have this problem ?

Comment: Missing `$` in `trim(codePostal);` => _"undefined constant"_

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake just in here in my code it's fine

Comment: _"that was a mistake just in here"_ - Always strive to copy/paste your actual code instead or rewriting it here, to minimize these kinds of errors.

Comment: I did copy/paste but I modified the name and missed the $,I edited my code to fix it :)

Comment: Do some debugging. Open the network tab in the browsers developer console and check that you send what you expect, dump the variables you get in PHP and what result your getting from the query etc.